# how to filter data from two django class

Tags: python, django, filter, view, get

I have two Django class，I want to filter VCDUnavailAudit by site_key in Django Get method, how could I do

```
enter code here
class VCDUnavailAudit(models.Model):
    user_key = models.IntegerField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
class User(models.Model):
    user_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    site_key = models.IntegerField() 
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_unavail_audit_records_by_site(request, site_key: int):
    availability_audit_records = VCDUnavailAudit.objects.filter
    serializer = VCDUnavailAuditSerializer(availability_audit_records, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a list all user_keys collected from users that have the given `site_key`.

```
user_keys = [user.user_key for user in User.objects.filter(site_key=site_key)]
```

Then get all the availibilty audit records that have their `user_key` included in the user_keys list.

```
audits = VCDUnavailAudit.objects.filter(user_key__in=user_keys)
```

**Complete view:**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_unavail_audit_records_by_site(request, site_key: int):
    user_keys = [user.user_key for user in User.objects.filter(site_key=site_key)]
    audits = VCDUnavailAudit.objects.filter(user_key__in=user_keys)
    serializer = VCDUnavailAuditSerializer(audits, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: This does not work and there are so many users match the site.
user_key = User.objects.get(site_key=site_key).user_key
Will only get one user right?

Comment: So you want to fecth all users or just only one user? I will edit the answer again for that.

Comment: All users with the same site_key. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer. please check again.